# How bad is partial load of association inverse side in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, partial

In a Symfony 2.8 controller, I get a field data with an association inverse side named `owners`.
At this point I have `$form->get('foo')->getData()->getOwners()->getInitialized === false`.

After that I perform some complex DQL query which can be simplified as :

```
"SELECT foo, owners
FROM Foo foo
LEFT JOIN foo.owners owners WITH IDENTITY(owners.bar) = 1
"
```

The important part is that there are several owners pointing on foo, but in the query we return only one of them, which makes subsequent calls to `foo->getOwners()` returning only one owner.

I see it as something dangerous because it means that accessing data via a DQL SELECT requests can actually makes you manipulate an association inverse side that is not synchronized with the database. I would not expect a SELECT request to do this kind of things.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of asking you how bad is "partial load of association", you should ask yourself how unsecure is a framework without security fixes for years. If you're optimizing your symfony application, I strongly suggest you to upgrade it. IMO, upgrade to Symfony5 or 6 should be your first step.

Comment: Than you for the advice. Although the question looks like I am trying to optimize things, I am actually making sure that I have properly fixed a bug that I have spent hours on (association is partialy load due to this query, which is why I don't fully see it).

Comment: It's been that way ever since Doctrine 2 was released back in 2010 or so.  Dangerous is a fairly subjective term.  Maybe quirky would be better.  The first time you call something like getOwners then lazy load will hit the database and load in all the owners.  But if you already have at least one owner attached then it just returns whatever it currently has.  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad, I'm satisfied with your answer.